# I cannot install .apk which have geneteted from AndroidStudio on my phone

Tags: android, android-install-apk

As I have stated in the title I'm struggling with .apk I cannot install application on my phone I'm getting app not installed. But when installing via usb I'm able to install application on the emulator phone. It’s always showing **App Not Installed** on mobile phone.
When I run application via AndroidStudio to USB the application has been installed. I do not know where I should looking for issues. May be someone had the similat issue.

Comment: Some times builds may be courrpted try rebuilding app and make sure in your device allow app installation from unknown resource enabled

Comment: I have done rebuild app and I have checked whether I have allow app install for unknown resources on my phone but still the same problem. In the first phase creating app when I had been checking app the install on my phone it's works. I'm not sure what happend.

Comment: I have done rebuild again and I have builded apk by Build/Build Bundles/Build AP as mention @ror, and iit have worked. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can try:

1. First of all build your apk by `Build/Build Bundles/Build APK` and not just by creating apk as a side effect of simply running the app under Android Studio
2. Make sure no other flavors are installed on your device - sometimes devices offer "Uninstall for all users" - that's what you should be looking for.

Comment: I have done it as in the first point which you gave me in your the comment. I very appriciate your help.